# Batch file for loop convert to shell script

Tags: shell, batch-file, converters

Can anybody help in converting this batch file code to Unix Shellscript.

```
setlocal    enabledelayedexpansion

set myfiles=
for %%f in (testfiles\\*.pcap) do set myfiles=!myfiles! %%f
mergecap -w testfiles\\tcpdump.pcap %myfiles%
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey, 

    Can anybody help in converting this batch file code to Unix Shellscript.
    For %%f in (f\\*) do (
    tshark -r %%f -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e tcp.srcport -e ip.dst -e tcp.dstport -e tcp.seq -e tcp.ack -e tcp.window_size -e tcp.flags -e http.request.method -e http.response.code -e frame.time_epoch -e ip.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f> out\\%%f.csv
     )
    goto :eof


Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you can write:

```
mergecap -w testfiles/tcpdump.pcap testfiles/*.pcap
```